# Race condition with load event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So this is more or less the code

Sorry for the syntax, I typed it from my phone

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    if (response){
    document.addEventListener('load', () => {/* remove spinner using jquery */});
} else { /* redirect to somewhere else */}
  })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SomeComponent />
    );
  }
}
```

I used addEventListener with React because I couldn't find any other way to bind the removal of the loading spinner to the load event.

The issue is that there is a race here, for slow network stations or fast CPUs ones, the load event may be launched long before the request is resolved, which results in the loading spinner to remain.

Is there maybe a way to check if the load event was already lanched?

If I can do that, I'll be able to check it after adding the event listener and in case it was already launched, I'll remove the spinner manually.

Comment: Why using jQuery with react while you can simply setState? (which trigger the render method in which you can display or not the spinner). I recommend you Read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: setState re-renders the component, i would like to avoid it. I think it's much simpler to set the loading spinner display to none.

Comment: But that is not the issue here

Answer (score 3):

I would't use jquery for this task (**or at all in react**) as you can do it in a more "reactish" way.
You can store the data in your `state` and conditionally render the component in your `render` method when the state has changed.
You can't avoid the first `render` by the way.

Small example:

```js
const Loader = () => <div>Loading...</div>

const MyComponent = ({message}) => <div>{message}</div>

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // mimic async operation
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({message: 'Hi there!'})
    }, 1500);
  }

  render() {
    const {message} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {message ? <MyComponent message={message} /> : <Loader />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> But then you re-render the entire component just to change the display
>   style of the preloader element, right?

Not entirely true i think you should read more about [Reconciliation and The Diffing Algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) and look at [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary) example:

> React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one,
>   and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the
>   desired state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I already did something similler. The issue is that componentDidMount is not synced with with the load event and can be launched long before. This causes the preloader to disapper long before the loading is done (especially when the network is fast and the CPU is slow). I need somehow to be synced with the load event

Comment: I'm not following, you set the state inside the promise's callback. that means your state in empty until the callback is invoked (this means that the first render should display the `Loader`) after the callback set the state a re-render is called and now the other component is returned instead of the loader.  where is the problem with this flow?

Comment: But then you re-render the entire component just to change the display style of the preloader element, right?

Comment: Thanks @Sag1v, this is definitely the more "React" way to go. However it does have some extra calculations I would like to avoid. I have found out I can use document.readyState to check if the load event was fired already. Thanks